# -bash: yum: command not found via SSH

Tags: centos, yum, upgrade

I'm trying to deploy a project to a remote server via SSH but I kept getting this error saying `command not found` no matter I typed `sudo` or `yum`. So far I've checked a few posts but still have no idea how to solve it.

My local OS is `Ubuntu 18.04` so I directly connected to the server by typing `ssh username@hostname` in the terminal. More data:

#### The output of `cat /etc/os-release`:

```
galtecch@s063 [/etc/yum.repos.d]# cat /etc/os-release
NAME="CloudLinux"
VERSION="7.5 (Viktor Gorbatko)"
ID="cloudlinux"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora centos"
VERSION_ID="7.5"
PRETTY_NAME="CloudLinux 7.5 (Viktor Gorbatko)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:cloudlinux:cloudlinux:7.5:GA:server"
HOME_URL="https://www.cloudlinux.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://www.cloudlinux.com/support"
```

#### The full list of `/etc`:

```
galtecch@s063 [/etc]# ls
./                       GeoIP.conf.default  mime.types       senderverifybypasshosts
../                      ghostscript/        motd             services
aliases                  group               my.cnf           shadow
aliases.db               host.conf           my.cnf.d/        skel/
alternatives/            hosts               nsswitch.conf    skipsmtpcheckhosts
at.deny                  ImageMagick/        odbcinst.ini     spammeripblocks
backupmxhosts            init.d/             openldap/        ssh/
bashrc                   inputrc             os-release       ssl/
blackfire/               issue               pam.d/           subversion/
cl.nodejs@               issue.net           passwd           sysconfig/
cloudlinux-release       ld.so.cache         pki/             system-release@
cl.php.d/                ld.so.conf          profile          system-release-cpe
cl.selector/             ld.so.conf.d/       profile.d/       trusted-key.key
cron.daily/              localtime@          protocols        trustedmailhosts
default/                 lynx.cfg            redhat-release@  vimrc
DIR_COLORS               lynx.lss            relayhosts@      virc
DIR_COLORS.256color      lynx-site.cfg       resolv.conf      wgetrc
DIR_COLORS.lightbgcolor  mail/               rpc              yum.repos.d/
domainusers              mailcap             rpm/             zlogin
environment              mailhelo            rsyncd.conf      zlogout
.etc.version             mailips             sasl2/           zprofile
fonts/                   mail.rc             scl/             zshenv
gcrypt/                  man_db.conf         screenrc         zshrc
GeoIP.conf               mc/                 security/
```

So as you can see there has `etc/yum.repos.d/` and here's what's inside:

```
galtecch@s063 [/etc/yum.repos.d]# ls
./  ../  centos-extras.repo  cloudlinux-imunify360.repo  cloudlinux.repo
```

#### Some yum commands:

```
galtecch@s063 [/etc/yum.repos.d]# uname -r
3.10.0-714.10.2.lve1.5.19.3.el7.x86_64
galtecch@s063 [/etc/yum.repos.d]# yum
-bash: yum: command not found
galtecch@s063 [/etc/yum.repos.d]# which yum
galtecch@s063 [/etc/yum.repos.d]# echo $PATH
/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/lib/path-bin:/usr/local/jdk/bin:/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/lib/path-bin:/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/lib/path-bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/opt/puppetlabs/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/home/galtecch/bin
galtecch@s063 [/etc/yum.repos.d]# rpm -q yum
-bash: rpm: command not found
galtecch@s063 [/etc/yum.repos.d]# find /bin/ /usr/bin -name yum
galtecch@s063 [/etc/yum.repos.d]# find /bin/ /usr/bin -name yum*
galtecch@s063 [/etc/yum.repos.d]# ls -l /etc/yum.conf
/bin/ls: cannot access /etc/yum.conf: No such file or directory
```

Comment: You might try contacting the vendor who provided you the host, or checking the documentation for that particular brand of Linux to see whether it uses some package manager other than `yum` for some reason.

Comment: Hmm... it seem that CloudLinux is _supposed_ to have `yum` as its package manager.  Do you know if the server has been deliberately crippled by removing tools?

Comment: instead of doing `sudo su` do `sudo -i`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have contacted the vendor and it turned out the root access is not allowed on the shared servers. I will try thinking of an easier way to do this. T